# Angular form reset is clearing the default selected value

Tags: angular

Im using angular 4 for my app and have a select inside my reactive form like this:

```
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="persons">
    <option value="" selected>Select default</option>
     <option *ngFor="let p of persons" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
   </select>
```

It works nice, first time it renders with the `Select default` option selected. But when i do a `myForm.reset()`, the form goes to initial state as expected, but the selected default value is no more selected. How can i reset the form and keep de default value selected?

Comment: try using `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`

Comment: Seems you need to do it like (or similarly) like the answer you got... https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#reset-anchor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you initialize the form in the constructor with default values, just set it back to the same thing.

For example, if in your constructor you set the form as such:

```
constructor() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['Joe', Validators.required ],
    });
}
```

then set it the same when you "reset" it.

```
public resetForm() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['Joe', Validators.required ],
    });
}
```

Comment: Make it whatever you set in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for this I have been searching and applying everything from all kinds of sources and this hit it head on

Answer (score 3):

From the docs: [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset)

> You can also reset to a specific form state by passing in a map of states that matches the structure of your form, with control names as keys.

```
constructor() {
 this.createGroupForm = new FormGroup({
  groupType: new FormControl(0)
 });
}
```

Set the default value again inside the reset method

```
public resetForm() {
 this.createGroupForm.reset({
  groupType: 0
 });
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="groupType" class="form-control" id="group_type" formControlName="groupType">
  <option value="0" selected>Closed Group</option>
  <option value="1">Open Group</option>
</select>
```

Comment: after adding selected to default option element it seems resetting form value by using reset method is no more usefull, if button type is reset

Answer (score 1):

Select Security Question

```js
this.forgotUsernameFrm = new FormGroup({
 secQues: new FormControl(null,[
Validators.required
])
})
```

```html
 <option value="null" disabled>Select Security Question</option>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am sure it would be helpful to the OP if you added a little on your answer to explain why it works. This would complement your code really well! Here's a few tips to write great answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

*While [Sureshraj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174574/3092298) gave a good answer, I will more directly address the question with a solution that still allows your default option value to be an empty string. To be fair, Sureshraj does have the proper method call except zero is passed as the default value.*

---

In cases where your default option value is an empty string, pass an empty string as the value when resetting the form group.

Assuming you have this template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="persons">
    <option value="" selected>Select default</option>
     <option *ngFor="let p of persons" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
   </select>

   <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

And your component is initializing the form group in its constructor, then you can call `this.myForm.reset({ persons: '' });`. This allows you to reset the form and select the default option without needing to re-initialize the FormGroup.

A more complete snippet of the component is below:

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = builder.group({
      persons: ['', /* validators go here */]
    });
  }

  cancel() {
    this.myForm.reset({ persons: '' });
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
}
```